# Proof that a derivative's points of discontinuity are all essential

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I'm reading Wikipedia's article on [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_%28analysis%29), and it says the following:

"Every discontinuity of a Darboux function is essential, that is, at any point of discontinuity, at least one of the left hand and right hand limits does not exist."

I've tried to look it up and all I see is that this is a corollary of Darboux's theorem. Could someone please clarify how exactly it follows?

Comment: The Wikipedia statement seems to be wrong. E.g., $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ in the domain $[-1,1]$ has a removeable discontinuity at $x=0$, yet $f(x)$ is a Darboux function.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is rather clear: assume that $\ell^- = \lim_{x \to c-} f(x)$ and $\ell^+ = \lim_{x \to c+} f(x)$ both exist. If $|\ell^+ - \ell^-|>0$, then $f$ cannot assume *any* value between $\ell^-$ and $\ell^+$ (or, more precisely, between two very small perturbations of them).

However I do not believe that this is a corollary of a theorem that deals with derivatives.